# how to get jenkins Configure and security setting through an API

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

## `` need to develop a Python script that displays all the settings of Jenkin results: Authentication type : # Matirx strategy List of all the setting values json or xml example code: import requests`your text` ``

## Jenkins API URL

jenkins_url = 'http://your-jenkins-url/api/json'

## Jenkins API request to get configuration information

response = requests.get(jenkins_url, auth=('your_username', 'your_api_token'))

## Check if the request was successful (status code 200)

if response.status_code == 200:
# Parse the JSON response
jenkins_data = response.json()

```
# Access the 'authorizationStrategy' from the global security configuration
global_security_config = jenkins_data.get('globalSecurityConfig', {})
authorization_strategy = global_security_config.get('authorizationStrategy', '')

# Print the result
print('Authorization Strategy:', authorization_strategy)
```

else:
# Print an error message if the request was not successful
print('Failed to retrieve Jenkins configuration. Status Code:', response.status_code)

Comment: Please edit your post so that code is surrounded by code fences (```) and other text is formatted as text so that it's clear which is which. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting